# Transfer from NRE account to salary account

Tags: india, banking, money-transfer

I am working in Kenya with an Indian company duly registered in Kenya as a branch. I am getting my salary from India in my salary account and I am also getting an overseas allowance from Kenya in which Company is paying tax to KEnyana Government. 
I am facing problem to transfer my own fund from my NRE account which is BOB Grurgram to my own salary account which is ICICI bank. when I am trying to transfer for any urgent expenses 'transaction is failed due to NRE account msg. is coming.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. I don't think anyone here is going to be able to help you other than to tell you to call both banks.

Comment: Presumably you are an NRI (since you are working in Kenya and presumably there for more than 182 days each year)? If so, you are not supposed to have _ordinary_ savings accounts in India and must convert all such accounts to NRO accounts. Perhaps this is why ICICI Bank is refusing to accept the transfer or Bank of Baroda is refusing to initiate the transfer?  What dod the "msg os coming" have to tell you abut why the transfer failed ten days ago?